# Moodle - Ubuntu configuration for links on 12.04 - 32 bit

Tags: 12.04, networking, apache2, cms, moodle

I have installed moodle on a server with an IP address of A.B.C.D, using the command

```
sudo apt-get install moodle
```

This site is sucessfully running on the following address

```
http://localhost/moodle
```

However, when I try to access moodle from another computer on the network, it so happens that all the links are absolute and not relative, i.e. all links are shown as `localhost/moodle/login.php` for example.

Any clues on the configuration on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say how you installed moodle, this is important to know. From the looks of it, you used an Ubuntu package, when you install it asks you for the "URL for the Moodle site", which defaults to `http://localhost/moodle`. This maps to Moodle's `$CFG->wwwroot` setting, and you'd need to adjust it to have a URL with your server's actual IP address or, better yet, fully-qualified domain name.

There are two main ways to do this:

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure moodle` will run Moodle's basic setup process again and ask you for the URL. Remember to say "NO" when it asks you to reconfigure the database, otherwise it will destroy any changes you made.
2. Manually edit `/etc/moodle/config.php` and change `$CFG->wwwroot`. The file is owned by the root user so you need to use `sudo` to invoke your preferred text editor.